# How to prove a theorem in logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

> Let $SF=(V,Wffs,A,R)$ be a formal system defined by:
>
> $V=\{ 1, +,=\}$
>
> $Wffs=\{1^m+1^n= 1^p \ with \ n,m,p>=0\}$
>
> $A=1+1=1^2$ ($A$ stands for axiom)
>
> $R=\{r_1,r_2\}$
>
> $ \ \ \ r_1: 1^m+1^n=1^p\vdash1^{m+1}+1^{n}=1^{p+1} $
>
> $ \ \ \ r_2: 1^m+1^n=1^p\vdash1^{m}+1^{n+1}=1^{p+1} $

I want to show that $1^2+1^3=1^5$ is a theorem (it can be deduced without any hypetesis).

Should I proove it like this:

$1) 1+1=1^2 \ (A)$

$2) 1+1=1^2\vdash 1^2+1= 1^3 \ r_1(1)$

$3) 1^2+1=1^3 \ MP(1,2)$

$4) 1^2+1=1^3\vdash 1^2+1^2= 1^4 \ r_1(2)$

$5) ...$

**Or** can I skip the MP stage and only do:

$1) 1+1=1^2 \ (A)$

$2) 1+1=1^2\vdash 1^2+1= 1^3 \ r_1(1)$

$3) 1^2+1=1^3\vdash 1^2+1^2= 1^4 \ r_1(2)$

$4) ...$

Comment: I suppose there should be a "$=1^p$" before the $\vdash$ in each of your rules?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Yes! Sorry, such a shame....

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your proposals are valid proofs. A proof must be a sequence of wffs, but what you have is a sequence of strings that contain the $\vdash$ symbol, and such things *are not wffs* in your system.

Also, you shouldn't refer to MP, because MP is not one of the rules of inference you have available in your system. There are only the two rules you have given, and neither of those is MP.

What this looks like is that you're confusing the $\vdash$ symbol that we use to write down rules of inference, with the $\to$ symbol from propositional logic. If you have a logic with $\to$ in its language, it will usually have an MP rule $\phi\to\psi, \phi\vdash \psi$, but that's not the system you're working with here.

What a rule of inference such as $1+1=1111\vdash 1+11=11111$ means is that *if* you already have a line reading $1+1=1111$ in your proof, you're allowed to write $1+11=11111$ later in the proof, by referring to the rule. But the rule *itself* does not need to be a line in your proof (and is not allowed to be, either).

So, assuming that your axiom $A$ was supposed to be $1+1=11$ instead of $1+1=1$, your proof could start
$$\begin{array}{lll}
1. & 1+1=11 & A \\
2. & 1+11=111 & 1, r_2 \\
3. & 11+11=1111 & 2, r_1 \\
& \cdots & \end{array}$$

Comment: okay, thanks for your help, I was wrong. Does your answer still stands with what my errors corrected? Do you feel I am still confusing $\vdash$ and $\rightarrow$? I've one last question: How to conclude? Is it when a rule let me to  $1^2+1^3=1^5$?

Comment: @Marine1: I don't see the main error corrected; both of your proposed proofs _still_ have lines that are not wffs.